# How to use different test package on different platforms

Tags: python, unittest2

I come from a C++ background, my Python knowledge is very limited, I need help with the following situation:

**Background:**

> We have a software `SF`, which is integrated into a large system `S`, this system `S` uses python `unittest2` as the testing framework (however tweaked). Specifically, it implements a class `A`, which inherits from `unittest2` and another customized exception handling class `B`. All test are then implemented based on `A`. System `S` is available on Linux only. However, this software `SF` is also used as a standalone application, which should only use `unittest2` when we test it on other platforms, in which cases class `A` is not available.

**Question:**
How could I apply different test packages on different platforms?

**My possible solution:**
I am thinking of implementing a wrapper class based on this thread: [Create a wrapper class to call a pre and post function around existing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466676/create-a-wrapper-class-to-call-a-pre-and-post-function-around-existing-functions). Answer from that post is put below:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self,wrapped_class):
        self.wrapped_class = wrapped_class()

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        orig_attr = self.wrapped_class.__getattribute__(attr)
        if callable(orig_attr):
            def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
                self.pre()
                result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                # prevent wrapped_class from becoming unwrapped
                if result == self.wrapped_class:
                    return self
                self.post()
                return result
            return hooked
        else:
            return orig_attr
```

However, I don't think the above thread is quite relevant since it is dealing with wrappers around class' member functions while I want some wrapper class that wrappers around different testing packages. Is it possible to do this in Python? I am using Python 2.7 FYI.

Any input is greatly appreciated and I am happy to add  more information if it helps to make myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: I'd use `nose` and its ["test packages"](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-packages) (or the test modules). Create a package for universal tests, and one for Linux-specific tests, then when the class is initialised, set its [`__test__`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html) attribute to the appropriate value. You could also use test skipping when the system is unavailable. Disclaimer: this is based mostly on skimming the nose docs briefly, but I think it should cover your needs.

Comment: @millimoose thanks for your input, but we cannot use `nose`. I will take a look at that and hopefully I can borrow some ideas from it.

Comment: It seems that `unittest` supports test skipping natively: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures, so it should be available in `unittest2`. Analogously, you could bundle per-platform tests in a [`TestSuite`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite) and only run the appropriate suites in your test launcher.