# Wrapping a class whose methods return instances of that class

Tags: python, python-2.7, wrapper

I need to write a class to wrap classes from third-party packages. Usually, the third-party class has methods that return third-party class instances. The wrapped versions of these methods have to convert those instances into instances of the wrapped class, but I can't make it work. I'm using Python 2.7 with new-style classes.

Based on [Create a wrapper class to call a pre and post function around existing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466676/create-a-wrapper-class-to-call-a-pre-and-post-function-around-existing-functions), I've got the following.

```
import copy

class Wrapper(object):
    __wraps__  = None

    def __init__(self, obj):
        if self.__wraps__ is None:
            raise TypeError("base class Wrapper may not be instantiated")
        elif isinstance(obj, self.__wraps__):
            self._obj = obj
        else:
            raise ValueError("wrapped object must be of %s" % self.__wraps__)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        orig_attr = self._obj.__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(orig_attr):
            def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
                result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                if result == self._obj:
                    return result
                return self.__class__(result)
            return hooked
        else:
            return orig_attr

class ClassToWrap(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def theirfun(self):
        new_obj = copy.deepcopy(self)
        new_obj.data += 1
        return new_obj

class Wrapped(Wrapper):
    __wraps__ = ClassToWrap

    def myfun(self):
        new_obj = copy.deepcopy(self)
        new_obj.data += 1
        return new_obj

obj = ClassToWrap(0)
wr0 = Wrapped(obj)
print wr0.data
>> 0
wr1 = wr0.theirfun()
print wr1.data
>> 1
wr2 = wr1.myfun()
print wr2.data
>> 2
wr3 = wr2.theirfun()
print wr3.data
>> 2
```

Now why on earth does `theirfun()` work the first time, but not the second time? Both `wr0` and `wr2` are of type Wrapped, and invoking `wr2.theirfun()` doesn't raise an error, but it doesn't add 1 to `wr2.data` as expected.

Sorry, but I am *not* looking for the following alternative approaches:

1. Monkey patching. My codebase is nontrivial and I don't know how to ensure the patch will propagate through the web of import statements.
2. Writing individual wrapper methods for all these tricky methods for each third-party package. There are too many of them.

ETA: There are a couple helpful answers that reference the underlying `_obj` attribute outside of the `Wrapper` class. However, the point of this approach is extensibility, so this functionality needs to be inside the `Wrapper` class. `myfun` needs to behave as expected without referencing `_obj` in its definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your implementation of `myfun` in the `Wrapped` class. You only update the `data` member of the class' instance, but the wrapped class' (`ClassToWrap` instance i.e. `_obj`)  `data` member is obsolete, using a value from the prev call of `theirfun`.

You need to synchronise the data values across both instances:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    ...
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
        if getattr(self._obj, attr, self._obj) is not self._obj: # update _obj's member if it exists
            setattr(self._obj, attr, getattr(self, attr))


class Wrapped(Wrapper):
    ...
    def myfun(self):
        new_obj = copy.deepcopy(self)
        new_obj.data += 1
        return new_obj

obj = ClassToWrap(0)
wr0 = Wrapped(obj)
print wr0.data
# 0
wr1 = wr0.theirfun()
print wr1.data
# 1
wr2 = wr1.myfun()
print wr2.data
# 2
wr3 = wr2.theirfun()
print wr3.data
# 3
wr4 = wr3.myfun()
print wr4.data
# 4
wr5 = wr4.theirfun()
print wr5.data
# 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer! It does get me partway there, but see the edit to the original question - I obviously didn't make this clear enough.

Comment: My code is just to show what went wrong and a simple fix. Would not necessarily apply in production. You can move the update of `_obj`'s `data` member into a static method in the `Wrapper` class and decorate `myfun` with the static method to enforce the synchronisation of `data` across wrapper and wrapped instances. There could also be other better ways to this.

Comment: unfortunately I can't rely on a decorator either in this case... `myfun` has to work on its own.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Well then, you can synchronise attributes (e.g. `data`) shared by the *wrapper* and *wrapped* (i.e. `_obj`) by implementing the logic in `__setattr__` in your `Wrapper`.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski See a sample implementation of such in `__setattr__`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Quick one, I updated the code with `getattr` instead of `hasattr` since the latter does not work for properties in Python2. See https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the assignment `new_obj.data += 1` in `myfun`. The problem with it is that `new_obj` is an instance of `Wrapped`, not an instance of `ClassToWrap`. Your `Wrapper` base class only supports looking up attributes on the proxied object. It doesn't support assignments to attributes. Augmented assignment does both, so it doesn't work entirely correctly.

You could make your `myfun` work by changing it around a little bit:

```
def myfun(self):
    new_obj = copy.deepcopy(self._obj)
    new_obj.data += 1
    return self.__class__(new_obj) # alternative spelling: return type(self)(new_obj)
```

Another approach to solving the issue would be to add a `__setattr__` method to `Wrapper`, but getting it to work right (without interfering in the proxy class's own attributes) would be a bit awkward.

Unrelated to your current issue, you're also potentially leaking the wrapped object in the `hooked` wrapper function. If a method you've called returns the object it was called upon (e.g. the method did `return self`), you're currently returning that object unwrapped. You probably want to change `return result` to `return self` so that you return the current wrapper. You may also want a check on the return value to see if it is a type you're able to wrap or not. Currently your code will fail if a method returns a string or number or anything other than an instance of the wrapped type.

```
        def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
            result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
            if result == self._obj:
                return self                            # fix for leaking objects
            elif isisntance(result, self.__wraps__): # new type check
                return self.__class__(result)
            else:
                return result              # fallback for non-wrappable return values
```

Comment: @BlckknghtThanks for this helpful answer! It does get me partway there, but see the edit to the original question - I obviously didn't make this clear enough.

Comment: I amended `if result == self.obj:` to `if result is self.obj`. The value equality test gave bad results when wrapping a numpy array. Hopefully that doesn't break your code?

Comment: Oh, I'd just copied that part of the logic from your code without too much thought. Using `is` is almost always going to be more appropriate in this context, since you do want to wrap new copies of the object getting returned by a method. Note that one of the big challenges you'll have proxying an object like an array is that operator methods (like `__add__`) won't use `__getattr__`, they're looked up directly on the class. You'll need to write your own versions of *every* operator the underlying object might implement. You may want to check if using inheritance will be easier.

Comment: If I could use inheritance, I certainly would. The extremely well known third-party package I am using is, apparently, deliberately written in such a way as _not_ to support inheritance.