# How to wrap a function as a class?

Tags: python

I have a function, say:

```
def func(arg1, arg2=5):
    blah blah
```

Unfortunately, a library that I'm using asks for an input to be instance of a class, so I cannot just pass my custom made function above.

I need a `class wrapper` around it, so that I pass: 
`MyClass(arg2=4)` and the result is the function shown above, ready to be executed with its second argument set to 4.

How can I do that?

My attempt: `lambda x: func(x, arg2=4)`

However, this is not an instance of a class. I want to mimic that library where their functions are instances of classes.

Comment: Please check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466676/create-a-wrapper-class-to-call-a-pre-and-post-function-around-existing-functions/1467296

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `__call__` function of a class.

```
class CallableObject(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
```

then you can "call" the class like this:

```
def func(arg1, arg2=5):
    return arg1 + arg2

callable_object = CallableObject(func)
callable_object(1, 3)
```

returns 4

**args in __init__**

To give arguments when instantiating the class you can add them to **init**.

```
class CallableObject(object):
    def __init__(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self):
        return self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Usage then becomes:

```
def func(arg1, arg2=5):
    return arg1 + arg2

callable_object = CallableObject(func, 1, arg2=3)
callable_object()
```

returning 4

and you can still call

```
def func(arg1, arg2=5):
    return arg1 + arg2

callable_object = CallableObject(func, 1)
callable_object()
```

returning 6 (arg2 = 5)

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Except that it is not exactly what I imagined. I thought I wouldn't need to redefine the function inside the class.

Comment: What about one of the arguments being set while instantiating the class? which is arg2 in my example

Comment: just move the `*args, **kwargs`, see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Using metaclass,  you can solve this

```
class MetaClass(type):
    @staticmethod
    def wrap(run):
        """Return a wrapped instance method"""
        def outer(self):
            print "PRE",
            return_value = run(self)
            print "POST"
            return return_value
        return outer
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        """If the class has a 'run' method, wrap it"""
        if 'run' in attrs:
            attrs['run'] = cls.wrap(attrs['run'])
        return super(MetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    class MyClass(object):
        """Use MetaClass to make this class"""
        __metaclass__ = MetaClass
        def run(self): print 'RUN',

    myinstance = MyClass()


    myinstance.run()
```

Comment: I think this is too complicated for me. But I will start looking into this metaclass beast. Thanks.